# Amend complex FILTER to search based on LIKE

Tags: google-sheets

In cell **E3** of the [`"Main_ST"` sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1psQKXUyk1bp-ek6g9K97NcbPYxWP2uOHqO-XzlJ_etk/edit#gid=1025462322), I have this formula:

```
=QUERY(FILTER(Raw_FullSTBreakdown!A:Y, (C3<>"")*(Raw_FullSTBreakdown!O:O=C3) + (A3<>"")*(Raw_FullSTBreakdown!C:C=A3) + (B3<>"")*(Raw_FullSTBreakdown!G:G=B3)),"SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col22,Col6,Col7,Col13,Col15,Col23")
```

This formula filters raw data from the `"Raw_FullSTBreakdown"` sheet based on the criteria in cells `A3-C3` of the `"Main_ST"` sheet. The problem I am having however, is that I would like the filter in the formula to work in such a way that it does not filter based on an exact comparison but rather a LIKE logic/REGEXMATCH.

For example, `"Raw_FullSTBreakdown!O:O=C3"` should not be `"=C3"` but rather a pattern match. This is because column O in `"Raw_FullSTBreakdown"` can have a delimiter "_" separating different FBA IDs - in such a case, an exact match FILTER wouldn't work.

For example in, Row 56 (and column G) of the `"Raw_FullSTBreakdown"` sheet we have `"B000VOHH8I_B00ARFFU1M"`. If I were to enter `"B000VOHH8I"` in B3 of the `"Main_ST"` sheet - this would not return this row 56 as `"B000VOHH8I"` does not match `"B000VOHH8I_B00ARFFU1M"`.

Answer (score 1):

*Change the exact comparison*

```
 Raw_FullSTBreakdown!G:G=B3
```

*part of the formula to*

```
regexmatch(Raw_FullSTBreakdown!G:G,B3)
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, I have tried this but I get the error:

`FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 33450, column count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.`

You can see this now on the sheet. It was working before I made this change.

Comment: the formula you shared above in the post description has one final closing bracket but in the sheet there's two closing brackets?!

Comment: Good point - it should be a single bracket. I have now amended this on the sheet but it shows "no matches" - even though the equivalent exact match formula (without REGEXMATCH) does generate a result.

Comment: Sheets regex(RE2) works with text(and not numbers); so for dealing with columns like EAN (which **ONLY** has numbers) go with `REGEXMATCH(to_text(Raw_FullSTBreakdown!C:C),to_text(A3))`